# Find the limit $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{((2n+1)!)^{2n+1}}{q+((2n+1)!)^{2(2n+1)}} $.

Tags: limits

Find the limit: $$ \large \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{((2n+1)!)^{2n+1}}{q+((2n+1)!)^{2(2n+1)}} .$$

**Answer:**

We know that  $ \ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\infty $. So $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{n}=\infty \tag{1}$$

Now,

$ \ \large \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{((2n+1)!)^{2n+1}}{q+((2n+1)!)^{2(2n+1)}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{q}{((2n+1)!)^{2n+1}}+((2n+1)!)^{2n+1}}=0$, by using $(1)$.

Am I right?

Comment: Looks good (assuming $q$ is a constant). It's like $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{N}{q+N^2}( =0)$.

Comment: You can as well use that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty$ and $(n!)^n\geq n!\geq n$.